# What structure topology optimization software generates truss-like structures?

Tags: windows, modeling

In short words I'm trying to perform a topology optimization for an aircraft engine pylon. [Here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33811/engine-pylon-design) you can find the context of my problem and the goal I'm perusing. But the results I'm obtaining are too raw. For an instance here's what I'm trying to obtain.

[image: trying to obtain]

And what I'm actually obtaining.

[image]

I've not clarified lot's of boundary conditions and non-design areas to save time иut anyway I think I need to have more control over the algorythm of topology optimization to get more **truss-like** structure.

What soft could you suggest as a most tunable & feachured structure topology optimization soft? To be more specific:

- Ability to **tune the number of trusses**. E.g. five thin trusses are more preferable than one thick. So I have more dissipated or... distributed structure.
- It's desirable that buckling demands is taken into account while optimizing a topology.
- It's desirable to have a feature of conversion of mesh model into spline model.

*Budget doesn't matter now.*
*Operating system - Windows 7 Sp1.*

Comment: What exactly do you want to tune? What exact features are required?

Comment: Also, what is your budget? And what is your operating system?

Comment: Please include that info in your question, comments get deleted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FYI : The 3rd part on the image is optimized on Altair's Optistruct software.
The optimisation you've done on Inspire run on Optistruct too.It might need to add some loadcases and to reduced the element size to obtain a comparable structure ...
Some information are availiable here :
https://www.slideshare.net/altairhtcus/large-scale-topological-optimisation-aircraft-engine-pylon-case

Regards